# How to get the first Some of an HList when composing Spray directives (Shapeless, Scala)

Tags: spray, shapeless

Let's say that I want to create a simple directive to fetch a session identifier off the HTTP request but with a twist:  The request might be using an old format but either should be considered valid for the moment because of backwards compatibility.

I sketched out something simple that basically composes two existing directives together with the resulting directive being a...

```
Directive[Option[String] :: Option[String] :: HNil]
```

Here's the meat of my question:  Are there any concise ways that to basically say "given a Directive that is an HList of multiple Option's, get the first Some and use that otherwise use a default value"?

My current implementation.  Works but seems a bit messy and isn't re-usable at all.

```
def sessionIdentifier: Directive1[String] = {
  (optionalHeaderValueByName("New-Session-Header") & parameter("oldsessionparam"?)).hmap {
    case Some(x) :: _ :: HNil if x.nonEmpty => x
    case _ :: Some(x) :: HNil if x.nonEmpty => x
    case _ => getNewSessionId()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the element types are guaranteed to be of type `Option[String]` then the following will be a little terser,

```
@ import shapeless._
import shapeless._

@ val opts = Option.empty[String] :: Option("foo") :: Option("bar") :: HNil
opts: Option[String] :: Option[String] :: Option[String] :: HNil = ...

@ opts.toList.flatten.headOption.getOrElse("default")
res0: String = "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is quite good actually. It may be refactored as

```
val sessionParameters =
  optionalHeaderValueByName("New-Session-Header") & parameter("oldsessionparam".?)

val sessionIdentifier =
  sessionParameters.hmap {
    case newId :: oldId :: HNil =>
      newId.filter(_.nonEmpty)
        .orElse(oldId.filter(_.nonEmpty))
        .getOrElse(getNewSessionId())
  }
```